# Loading image in for loop with jinja2/django

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

How do I dynamically display an image using jinja2 and django on a webpage.

Currently I am trying to load images in a for loop like:

```
{% for img_path in imgs %}
   <img src="{% static "{{img_path|safe}}" %}" alt="Herb" id="plant-mascot" style="width: 100px"/>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this doesn't work. The image path (imgs) is definitely correct. I have also tried loading the same image without passing it as a variable and it displays it.

I think I am missing something with jinja and html, I assume jinja isn't passing the text img_filepath to html but an object or something?

How do I make this work do I can display an arbitrary amount of images on a webpage?

The variable imgs is a list containing img paths e.g:

```
['img/im1.jpg', 'img/im2.jpg',...]
```

Expected Output:

A webpage with all images ('im1.jpg', 'im2.jpg', ...) displayed on webpage

Actual Output:

An empty webpage

Comment: Could you add the expected output and the actual output? What are the contents of `imgs`?

Comment: If you're already inside `{% %}` tags, you don't need to enclose variable names in double curly braces.  Just use the plain variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to look at the generated HTML, using the "view page source" command of your browser. You'll likely see the syntax of your Jinja template is not correct:

- Nested "{%" and "{{" (As @JohnGorden noted).
- Also "static" is a function in Jinja and can better look like this "static('url')".

Something like this (untested) for the src attribute:

> src="static("{{img_path|safe}}")"

You probably also don't want to use the same "id" attribute for all images.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for img_path in imgs %}
   <img src="{{img_path|static|safe}}" alt="Herb" id="plant-mascot" style="width: 100px"/>
{% endfor %}
```